# BottomSheetState - targetValue property

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What happened to the `.targetValue` property. This was my old code, how can I migrate now that we don't have the `.targetValue` property anymore?

This is my old code:

```
 @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    val BottomSheetScaffoldState.currentSheetFraction: Float
        get() {
            val fraction = bottomSheetState.progress
            val targetValue = bottomSheetState.targetValue
            val currentValue = bottomSheetState.currentValue
    
            return when {
                currentValue == Collapsed && targetValue == Collapsed -> 1f
                currentValue == Expanded && targetValue == Expanded -> 0f
                currentValue == Collapsed && targetValue == Expanded -> 1f - fraction
                currentValue == Expanded && targetValue == Collapsed -> 0f + fraction
                else -> fraction
            }
        }
```

Comment: Compose version?

Comment: @Abhimanyu v1.4.6

Comment: I can see `targetValue` in later versions. But `progress` in not there anymore.

Comment: For reference - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/287390076